# TYPO3 6.2 RTE can't add buttons

Tags: html, button, typo3, rte

Iv got fresh installation of TYPO3 6.2, RTE enabled in user settings and RTE images enabled in extension manager.

I was trying to play with adding images through RTE but I stuck on adding all buttons to default configuration.

Iv tried with below configuration in both User/Page TSConfig but without any luck.

This is what I see in RTE window without any change:

[image]

i would like to enable all editing options like this:

[image]

User/Page TSConfig:

```
    ## Default RTE options
RTE.default {
        ## Disable RTE
    disable = 0

    addButtons = *

        ## Disable Typo3 specific browsers
    disableTYPO3Browsers = 0

        ## Default target for links
    defaultLinkTarget >

        ## Disable contextual menu
    disableContextMenu = 0
    disableRightClick = 0

        ## Display status bar
    showStatusBar = 1

        ## Disable color picker
    disableColorPicker = 0

        ## Disable color selector
    disableSelectColor = 0

        ## Specifies that Mozilla/Firefox should use style attributes or not. When enabled, Mozilla/Firefox use span tags with style attributes rather than tags such as b, i, font, etc.
    useCSS = 0

        ## Disable enter key for new paragraphs creation
    disableEnterParagraphs = 0

        ## Remove trailing BR if any
    removeTrailingBR = 1
}

    ## Frontend RTE configuration
RTE.default.FE < RTE.default

    ## Full screen for bodytext (tt_content)
TCEFORM.tt_content.bodytext.RTEfullScreenWidth= 100%
```

Answer (score 0):

The usage of images in the RTE must be enabled in the extension manager. Navigate to the extension manager, select the extension "RTE", click the config-button and check the box "enable images".

Comment: Images are enabled in RTE options in extension manager.
It is not only images, I cant see buttons for editing tables and many more.
I want view like this:
http://www.training-typo3.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/05/TYPO3-RTE-size-default1.gif

Answer (score 0):

Add following code to TSConfig of your root page:

```
RTE.default.toolbarOrder := addToList(image)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this in Page TSconfig:

```
RTE.default.showButtons = blockstylelabel, blockstyle, textstylelabel, textstyle
RTE.default.showButtons := addToList(formatblock, bold, italic, subscript, superscript)
RTE.default.showButtons := addToList(orderedlist, unorderedlist, outdent, indent)
RTE.default.showButtons := addToList(insertcharacter, link,image, findreplace, chMode, removeformat, undo, redo)
RTE.default.showButtons := addToList(toggleborders, tableproperties)
RTE.default.showButtons := addToList(rowproperties, rowinsertabove, rowinsertunder, rowdelete, rowsplit)
RTE.default.showButtons := addToList(columninsertbefore, columninsertafter, columndelete, columnsplit)
RTE.default.showButtons := addToList(cellproperties, cellinsertbefore, cellinsertafter, celldelete, cellsplit, cellmerge)
RTE.default.showButtons := addToList(left, center, right, justifyfull,table)
```

for image you need to enable In Extension Manager open the configuration of htmlAREA RTE and enable basic.enableImages.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Use "showButtons":

```
RTE.default {
    showButtons (
        blockstylelabel, blockstyle, space, textstylelabel, textstyle,
        formattext, bold,  strong, italic, emphasis, big, small, insertedtext, deletedtext, citation, code, definition, keyboard, monospaced, quotation, sample, variable, bidioverride, subscript, superscript, span,
        fontstyle, space, fontsize, 
        formatblock, blockquote, insertparagraphbefore, insertparagraphafter, 
        left, center, right, justifyfull, 
        orderedlist, unorderedlist, definitionlist, definitionitem, outdent, indent, 
        textcolor, bgcolor, textindicator, 
        editelement, showmicrodata, emoticon, insertcharacter, line, link, unlink, image, user, acronym, 
        findreplace,
        chMode, inserttag, removeformat, 
        copy, cut, paste, pastetoggle, pastebehaviour, 
        undo, redo, 
        table, toggleborders, 
        tableproperties, tablerestyle, 
        rowproperties, rowinsertabove, rowinsertunder, rowdelete, rowsplit, 
        columnproperties, columninsertbefore, columninsertafter, columndelete, columnsplit, 
        cellproperties, cellinsertbefore, cellinsertafter, celldelete, cellsplit, cellmerge
    )
}
```